# When do exceptions from fire and forget Tasks get raised in the calling thread?

Tags: .net, exception, .net-4.0, task-parallel-library

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997415%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

> If you do not wait on a task that propagates an exception, or access
>   its Exception property, the exception is escalated according to the
>   .NET exception policy when the task is garbage-collected. When
>   exceptions are allowed to bubble up back to the joining thread, then
>   it is possible that a task may continue to process some items after
>   the exception is raised.

I assumed that the Task class has a finalizer that raises the exception or something. But then why does the following seem to run indefinitely?

```
long collectionCount = 0;

Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { throw new NotImplementedException(); });

while (true)
{
    GC.Collect();
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
    ++collectionCount;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since .Net Framework 4.5, [unobserved exceptions from `Task`s no longer crash the process when they are finalized](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2011/09/28/task-exception-handling-in-net-4-5/). This means your code is running on .Net 4.5 (or newer) and so you're getting the new, non-crashing behavior.

Comment: But I'm using Visual Studio 2010 and Target framework in project properties is set to .NET Framework 4 Client Profile.

Comment: That does not matter. What matters is which framework is actually used to run the program.